# How store string with accent in MongoDB?

Tags: string, mongodb, storage, non-ascii-characters, database

I use MongoDB and I want to store a string with accent but my database don't work if there are them.

If I take off it, it store string without problems.

```
foreach ($user as $key=>$value){
   $value = utf8_encode($value);
}

$conn = new Mongo ();
   if ($conn) {
$db = $conn->RecipeWorld;
$utenti = $db->users;
$result = $utenti->insert ( $user );
```

This code creates to me an empty database, only the name of it.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Could you show us your code and error message?

Comment: Strings must be stored as UTF-8.

Comment: I've edited my message with your requests.